# Octave Sockets Package, how to receive large data streams

Tags: sockets, octave

I still have problems with Octave. I need to receive large (>10M) images via a web socket connection, process the data and send it back. I work with Octave 4.2.1 in Windows 7, the sockets package is version 1.2.0 and can be found here: https://octave.sourceforge.io/sockets/

Here is the minimal code example:

```
pkg load sockets;

rcv_sck=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
bind(rcv_sck,12345);
a=listen(rcv_sck,0);
b=accept(rcv_sck);

data = [];
bufflen = 4600;

total = 0;
count = 0;

while (total < 10000)
    [buff,count]=recv(b, bufflen);
    data = horzcat(data, buff);
    total += count;
endwhile

disconnect (b);
disconnect (rcv_sck);

fileID = fopen('data.jpg','w');
fwrite('data.jpg', data);
fclose(fileID);
imshow ('data.jpg')
```

it can be tested with netcat

> ncat.exe 127.0.0.1 12345 < test.jpg

My problem is, that I am not able to receive data bigger than 4608 bytes. If I send more data, the receive array is cut to this size. This is why i choose 4600 bytes as a buffer length. Now I try to put the chunks of small data blocks together to get the correct data.

But this has two serious issues:

1) I have to know the size of the data I am sending, a problem which can be solved by sending the size first as a parameter. In my example i have set the size to 10000 bytes.

2) More important: it is terribly slow. For a jpeg of 170kB it takes 7 seconds to send the data.

Any hints or tipps are greatly appreciated, thank you.

jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read data until disconnect I would suggest

```
data = recv (b, Inf, MSG_WAITALL);
```

without any loop or horcat. And on your client side (netcat) use -q0:

```
netcat.exe -q0 localhost 12345 < test.jpg
```

Btw, if you want to store it on the server side, why don't you use

```
system ("netcat -l -p 12345 > data.jpg");
```

in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could not find any info on that. It works perfectly.

Comment: Which of the two solutions are you using now?

Comment: netcat.exe -q0 localhost 12345 < test.jpg

i open new connections for every file i need to work with. thx again!

Comment: No, I was asking for the server side of course. I presented two solutions with octave-sockets (`data = recv (b, Inf, MSG_WAITALL)`) and the one using `system ("netcat -l -p 12345 > data.jpg");` which works without octave-sockets

Comment: Even if it’s a bit late, to clarify I use the octave solution. It works perfectly and is in use in a big production facility. Your other idea could not be used. Thanks again